# The cheapest Samsung Smart TV running Tizen with at least firmware version 1400

Tags: television, development

I need to locate a Tizen TV running at least version 1400 for work purposes. It needs to be Tizen because I intend to write Apps for Tizen. It needs to be at least version 1400 because that is where developer mode is accessible.

It is deceptively difficult to locate an acceptable device. We purchased a device already that was advertised with Tizen to test with. However, it does not update beyond version 1106.

The device we tried was UE32J4570SS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the best way to find a compatible Samsung TV is to check the firmware version on the Samsung Support pages. You can check that the downloadable firmware for that TV set is above 1400.

As a reasonable answer to this question, we found this device:

**Samsung UE32J5550 80 cm**

At a price of **327 Euros** at the time of writing.

Small enough to fit on my desk, and cheap enough to please the boss.